# I'm using the "System.Text.Json" library to deserialize my JSON file and I'm getting an exception

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the `System.Text.Json` library to deserialize my `JSON` file and I'm getting an exception.
[image: abnormal]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
namespace Framework.Test
{
  public class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          new JSONInfo();           

          // 读取JSON文件
          string fileName = "config.json";

          string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
          MyAttribute weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyAttribute>(jsonString)!;            

          //new MyAttribute { APP_NAME = weatherForecast };
          //return;

          Console.WriteLine($"D: {weatherForecast?.APP}");
          //Console.WriteLine($"T: {weatherForecast?.LOCAL_RESFILE_PATH}");
         // Console.WriteLine($"S: {weatherForecast?.LOCAL_PATH}");
                   
      }
  }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace Framework
{    
    public class JSONInfo  {        
        [MyAttribute]
        public string? APP;                    
    }
        
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]    
    public class MyAttribute : Attribute {
        public virtual object? APP { get; set;}       
    }
}
```

how to solve them?
Here are the attachments:

```
{
    "app":{  
       "AppName":     "PZ",  
       "Ver":         "1.0.0",
       "AppID":       "00001",     
       "GameRunState":"Debug",     
       "Logger":      true,
       "AppLocalPath":"",     
       "AssetsPath":  "/Assets/"       
    },
    "preload":{     
        "LoadType1":"Video",    
        "LoadItem1":""
    }

}
```

The above json code encountered an exception in deserialization.
The exception text is posted as an image in order to preserve more details.
[image: abnormal]

how to solve them?

Comment: Please provide the exception in the text. Also, can you provide your JSON as text as well?

Comment: Please attach the complete JSON as code snippet in the question. And would say the JSON is not valid. The JSON with multiple objects (array) should be in this format: `[{...}, {...}]`

Comment: "enter image description here" are abnormal image files etc.

Comment: {
    "app":{  
    "AppName":     "PZ",  
       "Ver":         "1.0.0",
    "AppID":       "00001",    
    "GameRunState":"Debug",    
    "Logger":      true,
    "AppLocalPath":"",   
    "AssetsPath":  "/Assets/"       
    },
 "preload":{  
  "LoadType1":"Video", 
  "LoadItem1":""
 }

}

Comment: The exception seems pretty clear, it doesn't like a comma immediately befote the cosing brace. Also I  thought only one top level item was allowed?? You have two.

Comment: @HAF Is this your complete json? Can you add this to your code? otherwise, your question could be closed.

Comment: Editing the question is troublesome, so I'll just paste it here.After "enter image description here" click, there are some images.

Comment: Also, as stated please put the json files in your question as text. Anything that makes it harder for SO to help makes it more likely your question will be either ignored or closed.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug of "System.Text.Json".

Comment: I can post my project if necessary, I need a solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.allowtrailingcommas?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-allowtrailingcommas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HAF
I typically use Visual Studio's "Paste JSON as Classes" and let it generate the Classes. For that to work, copy the JSON in your clipboard (control+c), navigate to a cs file, and then click "Edit >> Paste Special >> Paste JSON as Classes"

[image: VS 2022 Paste JSON AS]

Pasted a working code below:

```
namespace Framework.Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "config.json";
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            JSONInfo weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JSONInfo>(jsonString);
            Console.WriteLine(weatherForecast.app.AppName);
        }
    }
}

namespace Framework
{
    public class JSONInfo
    {
        public App app { get; set; }
        public Preload preload { get; set; }
    }

    public class App
    {
        public string AppName { get; set; }
        public string Ver { get; set; }
        public string AppID { get; set; }
        public string GameRunState { get; set; }
        public bool Logger { get; set; }
        public string AppLocalPath { get; set; }
        public string AssetsPath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Preload
    {
        public string LoadType1 { get; set; }
        public string LoadItem1 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution has helped me solve this problem. Thank you, Sekhar!

Comment: @HAF, Please mark my response as Answered - so that the correct solution is recorded.